# Can we use website data which is having wp rest api plugin?

Tags: rest-api

Suppose I have created an app that uses WordPress REST API plugin and displays the posts from the WordPress site.

Now, if I find the WordPress site which is having the WP REST API plugin and I am able to fetch the data from it (only displaying the data into the app, not storing it). Is it legal to do so as per WordPress or REST API license?

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood the question correctly, this depends on the website you are trying to fetch data from.

I would suggest you read the *Term of service* of the target site, and see if they have denied accessing/using their content by third parties.

If the contents are not copyrighted and free to use, then there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: There is no such thing as "not copyrighted" content. The question about copyright is whether it is a copyright violation tou use the content at some specific context

Comment: really? i can give you link to the websites which they announce in their term of service that you can feel free to copy, modify or distribute the content of the site. That's what i call not copyrighted since the word "copyright" means the right to copy!

Comment: you can call "not copyright" whatever you want, but in the real world there is no such term. There are all kinds of copyrights and the closest one to being "not copyright" is "public domain", but a creation enters that state usually 75 years after the creator had died, and unlikely to apply to anything modern

Comment: Yes, for example i will remember to call a lawyer before making an ubuntu copy since it's dangerous in "real world". Anyway i see no point in arguing about this, ignoring further posts.

Comment: if you compare downloading something to distributing something, you truly do not understand copyright law, but this is your life, and your money, not mine

Answer (score 0):

You should ask a lawyer, but in general the answer is yes, if you just display data from the original site without storing any bit of it on your server, it amounts to be equivalent to using an iframe which was declare legal in most places.

But again don't trust this answer as I an not a lawyer, and ask an actual lawyer.